# How to deploy the war in remote Weblogic server with eclipse.

Tags: weblogic

I am using weblogic 9 and i tried connecting to a remote server.

But first of all it is asking for Weblogic Home. Since i am connecting to a remote system how can i did not had the weblogic home directory on my system.

Again just to test i also installed the Weblogic on my local system and tried accessing the remote server.

I provided all the necessary values. It detected the running server.

But when i tried deploying a JSF web app it gave an error.

It is as follows:-

Module named 'HelloWorldJSF' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
weblogic.deploy.api.spi.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: [J2EE Deployment SPI:260041]Unable to upload 'E:\eclipseWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\HelloWorldJSF\beadep\remote_weblogic\HelloWorldJSF.war' to 't3://192.168.218.51:7001'
Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.

If i try to run the same JSF web app in my local server it is working fine.

can you please let me know how to configure the remote server connection in eclipse without having the Weblogic Home successfully.

Thanks a lot indeed!

Mithun

Comment: What is shown in the "Error Log" of your Eclipse?

Comment: yes eclipse shows this error in the Problem section

Comment: What about the "Error Log" section?